# Can I use odds ratio in Google trends?

Tags: odds-ratio

I want to compare the popularity of several fish types:
The way I'm doing it is by using a reference keyword (in this case "fish") and comparing it to whatever fish I'm interested in. 
I enter both keywords (fish and tuna or fish and salmon etc) in Google trends and it gives me an average of both keywords. Then I simply divide these averages and get an OR. 
I keep repeating this process for each fish type.
Can I do that? And would that be called an Odds ratio?

I'm hoping that this way I can get a feel of how popular each fish type is.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to compute an odds ratio to compare averages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The y-axis values returned by Google Trends are not odds -- it's not clear what exactly they are, to be honest -- so their ratios are not odds ratios.

Comment: No, but they do compare two keywords when I enter them. I'm thinking that if I use the word fish as a reference then I can calculate how popular a given keyword is compared to the word fish. Can I do that? Maybe it's not called odds ratio then?

Comment: Right, I see no reason why you can't compare the popularity of these terms using the metrics they give, I just don't think "odds ratio" is an appropriate name for those ratios.

Comment: Moreover, whatever Google trends returns, it is standardized.